# Variadic functions parameters pass-through

Tags: go, variadic-functions

**Situation:**

I'm trying to write a simple `fmt.Fprintf` wrapper which takes a variable number of arguments. This is the code:

```
func Die(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    str := fmt.Sprintf(format, args)
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%v\n", str)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

**Problem:**

When I call it with `Die("foo")`, I get the following output (instead of "*foo*"):

> foo%!(EXTRA []interface {}=[])

- Why is there "*%!(EXTRA []interface {}=[])*" after the "*foo*"?
- What is the correct way to create wrappers around `fmt.Fprintf`?

Comment: BTW, the Die function re-implements what [log.Fatal](http://golang.org/pkg/log/#Fatal) and/or [log.Logger.Fatalf](http://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger.Fatalf) are ready made for.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Variadic functions receive the arguments as a slice of the type. In this case your function receives a `[]interface{}` named `args`. When you pass that argument to `fmt.Sprintf`, you are passing it as a single argument of type `[]interface{}`. What you really want is to pass each value in `args` as a separate argument (the same way you received them). To do this you must use the `...` syntax.

```
str := fmt.Sprintf(format, args...)
```

This is also explained in the Go specification [here](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters).