# How to generalize function wrapping in Go?

Tags: function, go

I have the following interface:

```golang
type Selector interface {
    SelectOne(ctx context.Context, one A) (Result, error)
    SelectTwo(ctx context.Context, one A, two B) ([]Result, error)
    SelectThree(ctx context.Context, one A, two B, three C) ([]Result, error)
}
```

and the following implementations:

```golang
type Database struct{}
func (d Database) SelectOne(...) (...) {...}
func (d Database) SelectTwo(...) (...) {...}
func (d Database) SelectThree(...) (...) {...}
```

Then, on top of that, I want to add a cache layer that uses the very nice github.com/hashicorp/golang-lru library:

```golang
type SelectorCache struct {
    db        Database
    cacheOne *lru.Cache
    cacheTwo *lru.Cache
}

func (c SelectorCache) SelectOne(ctx context.Context, one A) (Result, error) {
    cached, ok := c.cacheOne.Get(makeKey(one))
    if ok {
        casted, ok := cached.(Result)
        if ok {
            return casted, nil
        }
    }
    fetched, err := c.db.SelectOne(ctx, one)
    if err != nil {
        return Result{}, err
    }
    c.cache.Add(key, fetched)
    return fetched, nil
}

func (c SelectorCache) SelectTwo(ctx context.Context, one A, two B) ([]Result, error) {
    ...
        casted, ok := cached.([]Result)
    ...
    fetched, err := c.db.SelectTwo(ctx, one, two)
    ...
}

func () SelectThree(ctx context.Context, one A, two B, three C) ([]Result, error) {
    ...
        casted, ok := cached.([]Result)
    ...
    fetched, err := c.db.SelectThree(ctx, one, two, three)
    ...
}
```

As you see, the cache layer is basically the same for each case with the only difference being in the underlying function. If that was Python, I could easily create a wrapper function that passes *a, **kw to the wrapped function. How can I rewrite that so the boilerplate gets gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention in a comment that the argument types vary.

In general, you can do this:

- at compile-time, or
- at run-time.

The run-time version is easier to code and use and is quite flexible, but of course has some runtime cost.  Perhaps you are trying to avoid this (which is fine, but brings to mind the old adage about measuring before optimizing).

The compile-time version is what you've written in your example.

> How can I rewrite that so the boilerplate gets gone?

For Go 1, there is only one way to do that: write a program to write your program.  This is what [`go generate`](https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/internal/generate/) is all about.  There is a [Go blog post](https://blog.golang.org/generate) about it as well.

In Go 2, there will almost certainly be [generics](https://blog.tempus-ex.com/generics-in-go-how-they-work-and-how-to-play-with-them/), and you can actually play with them a bit.  They will be the way to do what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a variadic function (see [Function types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types)) that takes arbitrary number of `int`s as arguments(zero or more) and process them in one shot. For e.g.

```
func (d Database) Select(ctx context.Context, numbers ...int)
```

You could just iterate over `numbers` in a `range` for loop and perform your desired actions. Your function invocation can remain the same as before though.

```
fetched, err := c.db.Select(ctx, one)
fetched, err := c.db.Select(ctx, one, two)
fetched, err := c.db.Select(ctx, one, two, three)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a simplified example, the argument types are also of different types. I was thinking of ...interface{}, but that would kill the whole thing, wouldn't it? :)

Comment: @qwe You could use variadic interfaces - https://stackoverflow.com/q/12334697