# How to pass variadic functions into another function

Tags: go, aws-sdk-go

i am working with [aws-sdk-v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2) and I want to make a minimum working example using "secretsmanager" service.

I am trying to follow the steps in this similiar [example](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/code-examples/kms/createkey/) which is using "kms" service.

here is my script:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/ec2/imds"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/secretsmanager"
)

func main() {

    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }

    client := imds.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    region, err := client.GetRegion(context.TODO(), &imds.GetRegionInput{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Unable to retrieve the region from the EC2 instance %v\n", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf(region.Region)

    svc := secretsmanager.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    input := &secretsmanager.CreateSecretInput{Name: aws.String("test")}
    
    opts := &secretsmanager.Options{Region: region.Region}
    result, err := svc.CreateSecret(context.TODO(), input, opts)

    if err != nil {

        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result)

}
```

error:

```sh
./main.go:38:46: cannot use opts (type *secretsmanager.Options) as type func(*secretsmanager.Options) in argument to svc.CreateSecret
```

so the error is obviously in those line:

```golang
    opts := &secretsmanager.Options{Region: region.Region}
    result, err := svc.CreateSecret(context.TODO(), input, opts)
```

from the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/secretsmanager#Client.CreateSecret), the function CreateSecret takes these input types:

```
func (c *Client) CreateSecret(ctx context.Context, params *CreateSecretInput, optFns ...func(*Options)) (*CreateSecretOutput, error)
```

I can't find out how can I create this `...func(*Options)` part in my context. Can someone please help me with this part?

Comment: look for the functions creating `secretsmanager.Options`, do not pass the options themselves

Comment: They often start with `With...`. Like `secretsmanager.WithEndpointResolver`, basically any function that returns a `func(*Options)` type, e.g. `func WithEndpointResolver(v EndpointResolver) func(*Options)`

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334697/variadic-functions-parameters-pass-through or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723955/how-can-i-pass-a-slice-as-a-variadic-input

Comment: @TehSphinX I couldn't get you example to work. I stuck at this point `secretsmanager.WithEndpointResolver(secretsmanager.EndpointResolver(secretsmanager.ResolveEndpoint()))` and don't know what I should pass next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```golang
    opts := func(o *secretsmanager.Options) {
        o.Region = region.Region
    }

    result, err := svc.CreateSecret(context.TODO(), input, opts)
```